# MediaWiki: Set image size based on text size

Tags: image, mediawiki

I am trying to make a template in MediaWiki to show an icon next to some text where the icon is visualisation of the text. I would want the size of the icon to scale with the text size, like larger when in a header etc.

Normally, the image reference would be created like this (example for size 20px):

```
[[File:Icon.png|frameless|20px]]
```

I have tried to use 1em for size, but it seems like MediaWiki only supports size in `px`.

Is there any way I can get the image to scale with text in MediaWiki without creating custom css for this?

Comment: It's marginal whether this counts as "programming" rather than just "using software". The reason the [MediaWiki image syntax](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images) doesn't support relative sizes is that it's resizing the images *on the server*, not just generating CSS. You'll need to write some custom CSS rules that force a client-side resize of the image.

Comment: Have you tried CSS, like `background-image` or `list-style-image`?

Comment: @IMSoP Good point about the "running on server" aspect of this. For reference, you should turn this into answer in the form "no it is not possible, because...".

Comment: @IMSoP By the way, it is definitely "programming". Even though it is not one of the basic programming languages, like C, Java, etc. it is a language where code is interpreted by a computer to "compile" into HTML. In a way it is comparable to Razor (and ASP from olden days), which is script language that compile and run server side and generates HTML that is sent to client.

Comment: Alright then; I actually drafted as an answer then changed my mind. It still feels like usage advice rather than programming advice, though.

Comment: Yes, well it is the best answer you could give to this question. It does emphasize the possibilities and limitations of this particular functionality in MediaWiki code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason [the MediaWiki Image syntax](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images) doesn't natively support relative sizes such as `em` is that it's not generating *CSS* to set the image size, it's actually *resizing the image on the server*. There is therefore no (trivial) way for it to resize dynamically based on a *client-side* text size (the user could zoom in, over-ride font-size CSS, etc).

Although there are various built-in layout options which do include some CSS, none seem to do what you need, so you'll need to set it to render full size, then force it to be resized on the client using some custom CSS.

You could [add a site-wide CSS rule](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CSS) for a particular class and make a [template](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates) to apply it, so once set up it would be just as easy at point of use as the native markup.

Comment: I ended up setting the size optimized for level 1 header (which will probably be the largest variant it will be used) and then used a css class to set the height of the `<img>` to 1em. This worked perfectly. If someone needs larger than that, they can always override the size with a size parameter I already support in my template.